# Angular 7 cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport - virtual scroll

Tags: angular, virtualscroll

Is there any event available with, cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport to find the element in the list is rendered or not. 
for example while scrolling through a list of  like below, is there a way to identify a particular li is rendered or not or a  set of new elements are rendered into the DOM.

- item
- item
- item

Answer (score 6):

I think the properties

> renderedRangeStream: Observable ~ ListRange ~ => A stream that emits whenever the rendered range changes.

and

> @Output() scrolledIndexChange: Observable ~ number ~

on **CdkVirtualScrollViewport** can help you with this,

**or**

> @Input() cdkVirtualForTrackBy: TrackByFunction ~T~ | undefined

on **CdkVirtualForOf**

which you can use as the following :

in the class

```
  ....
  @ViewChild(CdkVirtualForOf) vrlist: CdkVirtualForOf<any>;
  @ViewChild(CdkVirtualScrollViewport) vsv: CdkVirtualScrollViewport;

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.vrlist.cdkVirtualForTrackBy = function(a) {
       console.log(a);
    };

    this.vsv.scrolledIndexChange.subscribe((n: number) => 
            console.log(n));
    this.vsv.renderedRangeStream.subscribe((ls: ListRange) => 
            console.log(ls.end, ls.start));
  }
```

read more [here](https://material.angular.io/cdk/scrolling/api#CdkVirtualScrollViewport) and [here](https://material.angular.io/cdk/scrolling/api#CdkVirtualForOf)